# Simple MySQL joining

Tags: mysql, join

Having trouble understanding how to filter an images table by tag information in a second table.

So I have an images table with all the basic fields:

```
id |
title |
userid |
timestamp |
status
```

and I have a tags table:

```
id |
imageid |
text (contains a single tag)
```

What i'd like to do is simple: take a list of tags and get a list of images that have all of the tags in the list. I just can't wrap my head around it.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM 
    images a
INNER JOIN
    tags b ON a.id = b.imageid
WHERE
    b.text IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3')
GROUP BY
    a.id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 3
```

`'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'` is your list of input tags
The `3` in the `HAVING` clause is the input of the count of tags in your tag list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have duplicate tags per `imageid`, you can join against a query that counts the tags per id, limiting the tags with an `IN()` clause to the list you want to search.

Then using a `HAVING` clause, reject the items for which the count doesn't equal the number of tags in your list (those which have fewer than the complete list):

```
SELECT 
 images.*
FROM 
  images 
  JOIN (
    SELECT
     imageid,
     COUNT(*) AS numtags
     /* could also be COUNT(DISTINCT text) */
    FROM tags
    /* Put only the tags you want into an IN() clause */
    WHERE text IN ('tag1,'tag2','tag3')
    GROUP BY imageid
    /* If an image has all 3 tags, COUNT(*) = 3 */
    HAVING numtags = 3
  ) tlist ON images.id = tlist.imageid
```